# Modeling-Support Vector Regression (SVR) vs. Linear Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, svm, linear-regression

I'm a little new with modeling techniques and I'm trying to compare SVR and Linear Regression. I've used f(x) = 5x+10 linear function to generate training and test data set. I've written following code snippet so far:

```
import csv 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f1:
  train_dataframe = pd.read_csv(f1)

X_train = train_dataframe.iloc[:30,(0)]
y_train = train_dataframe.iloc[:30,(1)]

with open('test.csv','r') as f2:
     test_dataframe = pd.read_csv(f2)

X_test = test_dataframe.iloc[30:,(0)]
y_test = test_dataframe.iloc[30:,(1)]

svr = svm.SVR(kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1)
log = LinearRegression()
svr.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1),y_train)
log.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1), y_train)

predSVR = svr.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))
predLog = log.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))

plt.plot(X_test, y_test, label='true data')
plt.plot(X_test, predSVR, 'co', label='SVR')
plt.plot(X_test, predLog, 'mo', label='LogReg')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the picture, Linear Regression works fine but SVM has poor prediction accuracy.

[image]

Please let me know if you any suggestion to tackle this issue.

Thanks

Comment: When I use R (with the package e1071 which is just a binding to libSVM) to do the same thing (i.e. SVM regression with rbf kernel) I get reasonable results. I suspect that the reason is  either something python related or it is something related to the default settings of the hyperparameters of SVR and/or the kernel (gamma, epsilon, the cost C, ...)...

Comment: @araz, did you manage to solve it dear? I am stuck with the same problem as you can see it here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529975/support-vector-regression-prediction-graph) and i would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X = np.linspace(0,100,101)
y = np.array([(100*np.random.rand(1)+num) for num in (5*x+10)])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

svr = SVR(kernel='linear')
lm = LinearRegression()
svr.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1),y_train.flatten())
lm.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1), y_train.flatten())

pred_SVR = svr.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))
pred_lm = lm.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))

plt.plot(X,y, label='True data')
plt.plot(X_test[::2], pred_SVR[::2], 'co', label='SVR')
plt.plot(X_test[1::2], pred_lm[1::2], 'mo', label='Linear Reg')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');
```

[image]

The reason you were going nowhere was `rbf` kernel

Comment: Thanks for your nice solution. I've tried `linear` kernel and it works perfect. My question is that why it shouldn't work with `rbf`?

Comment: @Araz That's a good question that puzzled me either. `Poly` kernel with `degree` higher than 1 either does not produce an acceptable solution. `Poly` with `degree=1` does not produce an optimal solution in terms of least squares. All these puzzle me. What I'd suggest is to rephrase the question like "Why kernels other than 'linear' don't work for this toy dataset" and post it to CrossValidated with nice pictures that could be produced with the above code.

Comment: I'm puzzled too! This confuses me that why SVR fails for such a simple dataset. Great suggestion. I'll share this issue for sure.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is SVR with kernel rbf don't apply the feature scaling. You need to apply feature scaling before fitting the data to the model.

## Sample Code For Feature Scaling

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
sc_y = StandardScaler()
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we adjust SVR rbf model with constrains like this:

svr_rbf=SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)

we will see different result as below chart. Green Stars are new SVR_rbf model prediction. Hope it helps.

[image]