# Support vector regression - prediction graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series

This post is a continuation of my previous question found in the following link. 
[Prediction: Time-series prediction of future events using SVR module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357805/prediction-time-series-prediction-of-future-events-using-svr-module)

Running with some sample data, I am getting the following graph but it seems to be hard to interprete this plot. What can we make of this? Can we tell (or predict sort to say) when it is going to go up or down? Any help will be appreciated
[image]